Turbo::StreamsChannel how to "target" an HTML element by a css selector and not by ID
I have this html setup:
<%= turbo_stream_from "articles_stream" %>
<div id="articles">
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
</div>

I want to stream content to the last article in the #articles element.
document.querySelector("#articles .article:last-child")

I have tried this:
broadcast_append_to(
  "articles_stream",
  target: "#articles .article"
)

Doesn't work.
I see that in turbo 7 there is a new targets attribute that supports css selector. So I tried:
broadcast_append_to(
  "articles_stream",
  targets: "#articles .article"
)

Also doesn't work.
I don't see any documentation about targets in the turbo-rails documentation.
What is the way?

broadcast_append_to(
  "articles_stream",
  target: nil,
  targets: "#articles .article"
)

There is an open PR to solve this in a more elegant way.
